Path dependent expectation value
Suppose I play a game with dice with a complicated win condition, as follows:

You start rolling a d12
If you roll a 12, you replace the d12 by a d6

when you roll a 6, you win (let's call this path 1 to the win condition)


If, on the d12, you roll 3 or lower, you
replace the d12 by a d8

when you roll 2 or lower, you win (let's call this path 2)



In this way, there are two distinct paths to a victory, with different probabilities.
How would one calculate the expected number of dice rolls of any kind to get to the win condition?
Each separate path is easy to calculate:

$P(12 | d12) = \frac{1}{12}$,
$P(6 | d6) = \frac{1}{6}$,
$E(\text{win through path 1}) = 12+6=18$
$P(\leq 3 | d12) = \frac{3}{12} = \frac{1}{4}$,
$P(\leq 2 | d8) = \frac{2}{8} = \frac{1}{4}$,
$E(\text{win through path 2}) = 4+4=8$

My gut says you calculate some chance $p$ that you turn into path 1 before path 2, and then use a weighted average like
$$
E(\text{win}) = p \cdot E(\text{win through 1}) + (1-p) \cdot E(\text{win through 2}),
$$
but I can't prove that that's correct. Is this a valid way of calculating the expectation? If so, how would I show that? Also how would I begin to calculate $p$?
